# Linux which cd worked. But cd is a builtin command in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cd

I just learned Linux, and read the book "The Linux Command-Line". It says:

> `cd` is a builtin command in bash.

So we cannot find anything with `which cd`; but somehow it worked well in my computer:

```
$ which cd
/usr/bin/cd
```

It is because I use CentOS?

Comment: Yes. It will depend on your system and the shell you are in when you execute `which`.

Comment: Did you try `/usr/bin/cd /tmp` ? then  `pwd` ? You will be surprised. But POSIX is rumored to require a (non-working as wanted) `cd` binary!

Comment: Related (from [unix.se]): [What is the point of the `cd` external command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50058/what-is-the-point-of-the-cd-external-command)

Comment: This also highlights another related from U&L: [Why not use “which”? What to use then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For shell builtins use `help` rather than `man`. `help cd` will give you usage information. `which` is misleading since it only finds binaries. Use `type`.

```
$ type cd
cd is a shell builtin

$ help cd
cd: cd [-L|[-P [-e]] [-@]] [dir]
    Change the shell working directory.
...
```

Now as it happens, there is a useless binary<sup>[*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50058/what-is-the-point-of-the-cd-external-command)</sup> `/usr/bin/cd` on your system. It's useless both because the shell builtin supercedes it, and because it's impossible for a binary to change the directory of the parent shell. Try to use it and you'll find it does nothing at all.

```
/dir1$ /usr/bin/cd /dir2
/dir1$
```

Comment: It's not *quite* useless. It can be used to determine whether a directory exists and has `+x` permission.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You can use `test -d` and `test -x` for that. (I know that you know that, sure)

Comment: @hek2mgl, sure. I didn't say it had any *exclusive* use.

Comment: Dammit Charles. I debated putting in some sort of request not to get pedantic on me. ;)

Comment: Might as well ask a dog to not chase squirrels. :)

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/50058/22257. Although `cd` must be a built-in for it to have any useful effect, POSIX also requires it to be executable (via `exec`, `find`, etc) since it is not a *special* built-in. I don't know why it is not a special built-in, though, as defined [by the POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_14). Perhaps the work it does trying to change directories is sufficient to warrant making it executable as a beefed-up version of `test -d`.